# Microsoft Access 2013 Field Permissions

Tags: database, ms-access, permissions

I'm making an Access database which will be used by multiple people, but I want to make it so that only certain people can edit,add,delete certain tables or fields so data isn't accidentally changed wrongly, and so the data is read-only to the people who don't have permission to edit. Is there any way to do this? Could I even just have access to certain tables or forms password protected?

Answer (score 2):

Access used to have its own security model using an MDW file, but that went away sometime ago. So the short answer is "no". If you are able to introduce SQL Server into the equation, you could store the tables in SQL (or the free version SQL Express). SQL Server offers the security model you need, and you would then link the tables from SQL Server (ODBC) to Access. In this model, SQL Server is managing your data, and Access is your "front end". Once linked, access forms, reports, etc. really don't distinguish between local or attached tables, so all of your same Access skills apply. You can export the tables from Access to SQL using the export feature within Access, and choose ODBC. I'm not sure if you're comfortable doing this, but it's really not all that difficult.

If you do use SQL Server (or Express) you would configure the users and permissions on the tables themselves, using SQL Sever Management Studio. If a user that did not have update permissions, for example, tried to update a row from an Access form, Access would fire the statement at SQL Server which would return a permission error. You could also use SQL Security to implement Windows Authentication, and assign permission to network users. When the statements were fired at SQL Server, they would be authorized based on the users login (when they logged into the network). There would be no need for them to login again.

If you decide to go this way, let me know and I can guide you through it.